# Why isn't my function returning a Float Number

Tags: javascript, html

Why isn't this simple code returning the floating point (declared constants) dollar value? I've tried the parseFloat and it would not work. There is most likely a better way of doing this, however I'm a beginner but picking up the concept quick. Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <!--link to CSS Style sheet-->
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <title>Allen Ricardo's Dance Studio</title>
           <!--JS Script and function here-->
           <!--Prompt user to enter an age
           create variable to hold age
           create variables to hold constant ticket prices
           use relational operators and if/else statements to check        
           condition of age
           output the cost of the ticket.-->
    <script>

  function verifyAge() {
        <!--constant variables for ticket prices-->
        var TICKET_PRICE_1 = 3.00;
        var TICKET_PRICE_2 = 7.00;
        var TICKET_PRICE_3 = 9.00;
        var age=prompt("Enter Customer's Age: ", "");

           if(age < 4 && age > 0)
                document.getElementById("tickPrice").innerHTML="$" +     
 TICKET_PRICE_1;

                else if(age >= 4 && age <= 16)
                    document.getElementById("tickPrice").innerHTML="$" + 
 TICKET_PRICE_2;

                    else if(age > 16)
                        document.getElementById("tickPrice").innerHTML="$" + 
 TICKET_PRICE_3;
        }
    </script>

 </head>


<body>
<!--add image from previous assignment question here-->

<header>
    <img src="danc_logo.png" width="200" height="200" alt="Studio Logo">
    <h1>Allen Ricardo's Dance Ticket Prices</h1></header>

    <!--container 1-->
    <div id="buttonPrompt">
        <h2>Click on the button below to enter customer's age</h2></div>
        <!--container 2-->
        <div id="defaultDisplay">
            <p>Under Age 4 (age &lt; 4) cost is: <strong>$3.00</strong></p>
            <p>Between ages 4 and 16 (4 ≥ age ≤ 16) cost is: 
 <strong>$7.00</strong></p>
            <p>Older than 16 (age > 16) cost is: <strong>$9.00</strong></p> 
 </div>
            <!--Create button for user here-->
            <!--Container 3-->
            <div id="button">
                <button type="button" id="ageVerify" 
   onClick="verifyAge()">Enter Customer's Age</button></div>
                <!--Container 4-->
                <div id="output">
                    <p>The Cost of Allen's Ticket is: <span id="tickPrice">  
   </span></p></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I know it's very highly likely this is a toy program, but don't use floating point types for money.

Comment: Would you elaborate please why using floating numbers for money shouldn't be used?

Comment: `prompt` returns a string ...

Comment: Found the answer to the monetary and use of float/doubles for representing the data here from a post several years ago. Hopefully someday it will make more sense.

Comment: please read http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp before using floating point numbers, in anything.

Comment: @allendks45 Because floating pont nubmers don't follow the same addition rules as rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks, updated prompt with a parseInt() and see the variables are already set to double precision. Because this is small bit of code returning only one constant value per iteration I know adding " " at beginning and end of the constants will make it look the way I want. Did not think this was acceptable. Wanted the return to factor in the decimal notation. Cheers!

Comment: try innerText instead. innerHTML mixes html syntax to the value, it may go wrong more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the unexpected output with no values after the decimal is here:

```
if (age < 4 && age > 0) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_1;
} 
else if (age >= 4 && age <= 16) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_2;
} 
else if (age > 16) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_3;
}
```

When you want a set precision after the decimal point, use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), changing the code to:

```
if (age < 4 && age > 0) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_1.toFixed(2);
} 
else if (age >= 4 && age <= 16) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_2.toFixed(2);
} 
else if (age > 16) {
  document.getElementById('tickPrice').innerHTML = '$' +
  TICKET_PRICE_3.toFixed(2);
}
```

Note that this is a display convention, and not actually mutating the number represented.

The second issue is the use of `prompt()`

```
var age=prompt("Enter Customer's Age: ", "")
```

`prompt()` returns a String and would need to be parsed. You could:

```
var age = parseInt(prompt("Enter Customer's Age: ", ""));
```

[**Why not use floating points for money**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FloatingPointCurrency)

As an ancillary to your question and response to comments, consider the following reasonable situation.

```
var price = 0.10; 
var fee = 0.20; 
var total = price + fee;
```

Floating point numbers can't represent all values exactly. Since JavaScript numbers are all floating point numbers, integers within a range are a safe thing (-(2^53 - 1) to 2^53 - 1 specifically).

So if you output total, you'll get

```
 0.30000000000000004
```

That's incorrect, that's supposed to be 0.30.